# Can we use google Maps street view in ipad programming With annotations and other features of mapkit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

i was unable to implement google maps street view in my ipad.I was wondering if  there is any way to implement google street view in ipad with all the features of mapkit .
 i already tried it with java script but no success.

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Street view uses Flash in the browser (not available on iOS) and is a custom job in the Maps app. It's not available for use. Send your users to the location in the Maps app using a maps URL and let them get Street View themselves.

**Edit**

But... Here's a URL that will help you get images from Street View, but in the process probably violate the ToS for using Google Maps (and get any app rejected).

http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/15/google-streetview-static-api/

Comment: so that means there is no way to use google map street view in iOS programming...we can see only static images thats it??

Comment: Yes, unless you get into some very complicated programming, there's no way to put Street View into your app.

Comment: This post (http://mrdoob.com/blog/post/705) describes how they programmed a Street View interface, but it's very heavy duty stuff, and it looks like they had help from Google.